# js .append html element do not have javascript lib

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to use `$.ajax` to get html string from php file and append to current html div. when i try to use php `echo`, everything works fine, but when i try to dynamically load using `$.load` or `$.ajax`, javascript library doesn't load or apply to the div.

included js libs in header:

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MetroJs.lt.min.css">
<script src="MetroJs.lt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

script file in header:

```
function getdatafromphp() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "autoload_process.php",
    data: {group_no : track_load},
    dataType: 'html',
    async: true,
    success: function(html) {
    $("#results").append(html);
    track_load++; //loaded group increment
    loading = false; 
}
    })
}
```

html code in body:

```
<div id="results"></div><div class="animation_image" align="center"><img src="ajax-loader.gif"></div>
```

i put rest of css and js right after the div:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"/><script src="index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The html can be loaded into div, but it does not have any js effect to it (css is fine)

I suspect is because i use `$(document).ready` in both js scripts, but changing it does not help.

here is my test site: http://www.zsm.me/test/newindex/

Please help if you have any thoughts.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to bring in the data (html) into the specified div, then initialize the plugin for each of the elements inside the html.For ex:

```
success: function(html){
$("#mybutton").buttonset();
$("#dateofbirth").datepicker();
}
```

Comment: I just copied everything from my js library into the $.ajax success, and now everything works. it seems like it needs to load the js lib every time ajax dynamically append the html elements.... I don't have a better way to get the js file loaded, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Today i find a new method by adding

```
<?php echo $script; ?>
```

in the header.

I have no idea why this works but it does...
well, hope this helps